# php how to to do operation on date

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I have problem when i want calculate date. Simple Example:

I have `2013-09-01` is start date and I have 30day per month. My work i need alert tell to my user in 10 day before end month(it's mean on `2013-09-20`i must alert message `it's 10day more for end of this month`). So every one have any idea for help to calculate it. becuese i like can't (`+, -, *,/`) on date. Now i am some data like

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
    $current = time();
    $start = 1380188957;
    echo 'Start date: '. date('Y-m-d', $start) ."\n";
    echo '<br/>';
    $repeat = 30;
    $enddate = time() + ($repeat * 24 * 60 * 60);
    echo 'end date: '. date('Y-m-d', $enddate) ."\n";
```

Thanks in advent for helping.

Comment: For my Concept: I want declare `$current` to `sub` with `$start` if it's `smaller or Equuleus(<=)` 20, i will alert message

Comment: Hey Time. Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so could you accept one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Not every month has 31 days, you can get the number of days in any month by using the `t` option for the string format param in php's `date()` function.

```
// Current time as unix timestamp   
$now = time();

// Number of days in current month
$days_this_month = date("t", time());

// Last day of the current month as a unix timestamp;
$end_of_month = strtotime(date("Y-m-t", time()));

// Ten days before the end of the month as a unix timestamp
$ten_days = strtotime('-10 days', $end_of_month);
```

Now we can do a check to see if it is 10 days before the end of the month:

```
if($now > $ten_days) {

    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = 1380188957;
$enddate = time() + ($repeat * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

That's your own code. Using that we can easily compute `10 days before end date`

```
$alert=$enddate-864000;   // That's 10 days
$alertdate=date('Y-m-d', $alert);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much but i am need in dynamic one not want to know only static like that, Could you tell me how to calculate `4400`= `10day` ?

Comment: 1 day = `24 hours x  60 minutes x 60 seconds` = 864000. Now if you have to calculate 6 days just multiply that by 6 and you get the answer. But interesting thing is that its already a part of your code, see that `$repeat` line? that does the same thing. Sorry I had the number wrong, missing minutes. Just updated it

Comment: yes i have step to test with `10day, 6day and ...` thanks for your help i will test it now