# php how to compare day to near end than

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have 2 field in Database to relate my work (`start_date` and `repeat_nb`). with my old question [about how to alert color by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042145/php-how-to-to-do-operation-on-date)
I completed code like 
                `

```
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
     $today = date('Y-m-d');
     /**** This is just simple to show in browser to see data but not what to need********/
     $current = strtotime($today);
     echo "<br /><br />";
     echo 'CURRENT_DATE: '. ($today) ."\n";
     echo "<br /><br />";
     $start =1379437200;
     echo 'Start date: '. date('Y-m-d', $start) ."\n";
     echo '<br/>';
     echo '<br/>';
     /****it is just for get values of date that pass by values $date******/
     $date = '2013-09-18';
     echo 'Convert: '.$Convert = strtotime($date);
     echo "<br />";
     echo 'DisConvert: '.date('Y-m-d', $Convert);
     /**** start code for procees*****/
     echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
     $answer = ($current)-($start);
     echo "<br />";
     if(((($answer/24)/60)/60)==30){
         echo "red";
         exit();
     }
     elseif(((($answer/24)/60)/60) >=24 && ((($answer/24)/60)/60)<29 ){
         echo "yellow";
         exit();
     }
     elseif(((($answer/24)/60)/60) >= 20 && ((($answer/24)/60)/60)<29){
         echo "green";
         exit();
     }
     else{
          echo "nothing";
     }`
```

Yes Code above is declare by `start_date= 1379437200 = 2013-09-18` and  `repeat_nb = 30 day`;

My question:Color has been alert by date that i need but i want to Short it when i have much date show on screen by any color to group like green with green and which data near end of those color is show on up.(`EX: green color have 7 row but some row is just start and some row is near change to yellow`).

Note:`repeat_nb` for this code is just only **30day** but in real it's can set by user to **10day, 30day, 3month, 6month,...** .

Please give me some idea around it. I am looking to see your reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that will return color based on intervals :

#### Use example:

```
echo getColor('2013-09-30'); # green
echo getColor('2013-09-20'); # yellow
echo getColor('2013-09-01'); # red
echo getColor('2013-08-15'); # nothing
```

#### Code:

```
function getColor($date) {
    $now = new DateTime('today');
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $colors = array(
        '-7 day'   => 'green',
        '-20 day'  => 'yellow',
        '-1 month' => 'red',
    );
    foreach ($colors as $modify => $color) {
        $copy = clone $now;
        $copy->modify($modify);
        if ($copy <= $date) return $color;
    }
    return 'nothing';
}
```